# Как узнать номер строки?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

У меня есть таблица. Надо чтоб по клику по ячейке `jQuery` получал номер этой строки. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал вариант с `DIV`'ом у которого в стилях было прописано `hidden`. Есть ли еще какой-то скрытый тег, чтобы его не видел пользователь, но увидел `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзаем [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 1):

Без index():

```
$('#table td').click(function(){
    var n = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
});
```